# get Subject Key Identifier of certificate with openssl commands

Tags: linux, mono, openssl, certificate

i want to get get Subject Key Identifier of my certificate using openssl and also every x509 extensions property of my certificate but i didn't find any solution. please help if there is a way to do it.

I need the OpenSSL commands to do it.

Comment: Check this - http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certextensions.htm

Comment: @Prabhu  tanks for your answer but this is a c program but i need exact command line for command line in linux openssl.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned you need to find X.509 extensions via command line:

`openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text`

You should see that extensions are printed as shown here:

> X509v3 extensions:
>
> ```
>         X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
>             CA:TRUE
>         X509v3 Key Usage: 
>             Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
>         Netscape Comment: 
>             OpenSSL Generated Certificate
>         X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
>             58:47:30:77:3F:EF:AC:3D:5A:A3:BB:F6:7F:D2:CE:95:08:77:23:A0
>         X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
>            keyid:FB:7B:FB:7B:23:87:8B:FC:3D:97:33:11:6B:0D:37:A0:21:8D:E6:CD
> ```

Comment: thanks this is good for me. but is there a way that i extract some of them ? for example is it possible that just get "subject key identifier" ?

Comment: You can parse the output isn't? - `openssl x509 -in server.pem -noout -text | grep -A1 "Subject Key Identifier"`